# ayuda con jquery para seleccionar checkbox de tablas creada dinamicamente c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Que tal amigos tengo la siguiente problemática, estoy generando una tabla dinamica con jquery resultado de una consulta a un método de c# el metodo es

```
 public JsonResult GetRequirentes(string term)
    {
        var Result = from c in db.MtoRequirentes
                     where c.Descripcion.ToString().Contains(term)
                     orderby c.Descripcion
                     select new Item
                     {
                         id = c.MtoRequirenteId.ToString(),
                         value = c.Descripcion.ToString()
                     };

        return Json(Result.Take(10).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

bien para generar la table en html utilizo una función

```
function GetTableRequirentes(Id) {
if (Id > 0) {
    $('#tblRequirentes').show();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: _urlBase + 'Requirentes/GetTableRequirentes',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: Id },
        success: function (data) {
            var resultado = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.data));
            if (resultado.length > 0) {
                console.log(resultado);
                for (var i = resultado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    var rows = "<tr>"

                        + "<td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' id='" + resultado[i].MtoRequirenteId + "'class='case'>" + "</td>"                                                        
                        + "<td>" + resultado[i].Descripcion +"</td>"                            
                        + "</tr>";

                    $('#tblRequirentes tbody').append(rows);
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#FileUpload1').show();
                $('#Submit').show();
                $('#Resultado').hide();
            }
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Error al Cargar la información relativa a requirentes.' + ex);                
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

}

hasta aqui no tengo problemas, despues genero una funcion ara poder seleccionar todos los checkboc de la tabla

```
$("#checkBoxAll").on("change", function () {

    $(".case").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

este método me selecciona todos los checkbox que existan en la tabla, ahora lo que quiero es que al quitar la selección de un chexkbox(al no estar seleccionados todos) me quite la seleccion del checboc que marca todos.

lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera pero no funciona.

```
$(".case").on("change", function () {
    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

serian tan amable de poder darme una pista de como podria solucionar este problema.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

He simulado de forma bien simple tus checkbox, y la verdad lo que tienes funciona bien.

Dejo lo que e probado tal cual lo describes:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#checkBoxAll").on("change", function() {
        $(".case").prop("checked", this.checked);
    });

    $(".case").on("change", function() {
        if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll"> check all<br><hr>
  <input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox1"> check 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox2"> check 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox3"> check 3<br>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas, segun lo que preguntas y el codigo que colocas debe funcionar. Pero, como estas agregando filas a la tabla de forma dinamica, esas filas nuevas ya no se les amarra el evento `change` que programaste.

Para solucionarlo de forma sencilla deberias de implementarlo de esta forma:

```
$(document).on("change", ".case", function() {
    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

De esta forma cada vez que agreges una nueva fila, se suscribira al evento.

Tambien te aconcejo que revises que otros input le estas asignando la clase `case`, lo mas probable eso tambien te pueda estar afectando o afectar mas tarde (*si el proyecto crece*) cuando hagas el `$(".case").length`.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacer siempre referencia a los checkbox de una tabla en especifico, de esta forma si tienes algun otro input con la clase `case` no lo tomara en cuenta.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#checkBoxAll").on("change", function () {
      $("#tblRequirentes tbody input[type='checkbox'].case").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  
  $("#tblRequirentes tbody").on("change", "input[type='checkbox'].case", function () {
    if ($("#tblRequirentes tbody input[type='checkbox'].case").length == $("#tblRequirentes tbody input[type='checkbox'].case:checked").length) {
        $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#checkBoxAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
   });
   
});
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <hr>
      <table id="tblRequirentes">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll"> check all</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox1"> check 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox2"> check 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox3"> check 3</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="case" id="checkBox4"> check 4 fuera de la tabla
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="case">
   </body>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```